# onclick="window.open() is not working for multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, html

```
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 3;
url = 'https://www.google.com';
url2 = 'https://www.yahoo.com';
link_name = '<div class="j">Download File</div>'
var timer = setInterval(function () { myCounter() }, 1000);
function myCounter() {

  if (minutes > 59 || minutes < 0) {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Please check the minutes variable, Set it in between 0 to 59</font>";
  } else {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds == 0) {
      minutes = minutes - 1;
      seconds = 60;
    }
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds";
    if (minutes == -1) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<h3>Tile</h3>";
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "<a href='" + url + "' onclick='window.open(" + url2 + ")'>" + link_name + "</a>";
    }
  }
}
```

Hey guys I want to visit google.com in home tab and yahoo.com in new tab if click on "Download File". Don't worry about this Countdown javascript. Just I want to fix this phrase. `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="<a href='"+url+"' onclick='window.open("+url2+")'>"+link_name+"</a>";` I tried many times but I could only visit for google.com only. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need if conditions. Simply..

```
// -- Function to visit two sites

function multi(url1, url2) {
window.open(url2);
window.location.href = url1;
}

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = '<a onclick="multi(url, url2)">cLICK</a>\n';
```

Now it's 1000% working proof!!! Thank you so much Mister [Henrique Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10021999/henrique-rodrigues)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that allows you to open two sites at the same time. By default what you want. Otherwise if you want to open in different tabs you have to put true for the third parameter.

```js
// -- Function to visit two sites

function multi(url1, url2, twoTabs = false) {


    if(twoTabs) {

        window.open(url1);

    } else {

        window.location.href = url1;

    }

    window.open(url2);

}

// -- -- --
```

Now normally it should work. I added the missing minute.

```js
// -- Function to visit two sites

function multi(url1, url2, twoTabs = false) {


    if(twoTabs) {

        window.open(url1);

    } else {

        window.location.href = url1;

    }

    window.open(url2);

}

// -- -- --


var seconds = 3;
var minutes = 0;
url = 'https://www.google.com';
url2 = 'https://www.yahoo.com';
link_name = '<div class="j">Download File</div>'
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    myCounter()
}, 1000);

function myCounter() {

    if (minutes > 59 || minutes < 0) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Please check the minutes variable, Set it in between 0 to 59</font>";
    } else {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            minutes = minutes - 1;
            seconds = 60;
        }
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds";
        if (minutes == -1) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<h3>Tile</h3>";
            /* document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "<a href='" + url + "' onclick='window.open(" + url2 + ")'>" + link_name + "</a>";*/
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = '<div onclick="multi(url, url2)">Clic</div>\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh You're Genius! nice try! but unfortunately the code isn't work in your style! but, thankfully you showed me an another direction to solve my problem. That's why I said "you're genius". Here I fixed it. Read my answer on up there! and I thousand times thank you again! Good Luck!